# Working with JavaScript private methods:

Tags: javascript, node.js, private, privacy

I am following Douglas Crockford's tutorial on the visibility of JavaScript  variables and functions here : http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

I have written the following MyClass.js file and I am running it from the terminal using node. Below I show my output on the terminal and my class. I do not understand why I get returned an "undefined" (instead of just true) and also, why my console.log(log) is not showing anywhere?

```
$ node MyClass.js 
undefined
true
```

And my class

```
function MyClass(log) 
{
    this.log = log;
        var that = this; 
        function _evaluate (log)
        {
             console.log(log);
             return true;
        };

    this.evaluate = function() 
    {
    return _evaluate() ? true : false;
    };

}

 var myObject = new MyClass('this is a test');
 console.log(myObject.evaluate());
```

Comment: You get `undefined` because you are not passing an argument to `_evaluate`, hence `log` is `undefined` inside the function. Not sure what the expected outcome is... just remove the parameter?

Comment: Why do you have a parameter for the `_evaluate` function? Since it has the same name as the constructor's parameter (`log`), it's shadowed...and since you call `_evaluate()` (no arguments), it has an `undefined` value. Try doing `console.log(that.log);` (without a `log` parameter for the `_evaluate` function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `_evaluate` with no arguments, so it prints `undefined` once (line 7), then `true` (line 19).

Finally it prints `undefined` because your script as a whole has no return value.